# sendkeys() enters text and clears it in an auto-complete search field

Tags: autocomplete, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I am not able to get webdriver working on entering some text into an auto-complete based search text-field.
I am using the following code:

```
//here elmt is a WebElement variable.
elmt = driver.findElement(By.id(testDataMap.get("globalSearchTextLocator")));
elmt.sendKeys(patientName);

//Here I am finding the search result list once webdriver enters the characters.
elmt = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(testDataMap
.get("searchPatientNameLocator")));


searchedPatientsList = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(testDataMap
.get("searchPatientNameLocator")));
```

I also tried using `elmt.click()` before `elmt.sendKeys()`. It worked for a few random times I ran the test. But mostly, it fails.
What happens is webdriver enters the text into the search-field and clears it the next moment. This leads to no search result and fails the test. I am not able to trace the problem behind this weird behaviour. Any help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have face similar type of problem, but it is for numberic field. Try using this below code and execute ur script.

```
String accOffNoID = OR.getProperty("AccOffNo_ID"); 
        WebElement accOffNoInput = driver.findElement(By.id(accOffNoID));
        accOffNoInput.clear(); 
        accOffNoInput.sendKeys(String.valueOf(9874651230L));
        accOffNoInput = driver.findElement(By.id(accOffNoID));
```

Change the names according to your script and execute, it should work.